# Is there a limit to how many Multiple Response Sets I can make on SPSS?

Tags: statistics, spss

I am preparing a dataset on SPSS to analyze a survey I prepared on Limesurvey. This survey happens to have lots of multiple response set questions.

I have already done 20 multiple response sets via Analyze >>> Multiple Response >>> Define Variables. However, when I come to add more, the option to create another multiple response set is no longer present, even though I have inputted all the required info.

So, does SPSS have a limit on how many multiple response sets can be made or am I doing something wrong?

Also, what other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of MR sets you can define.  Be sure that you have entered all the required information in order to enable the Add button in the dialog.  Note that an MR set must have at least two variables.

If you can't get the dialog to work, you can define the sets via syntax, which would be faster anyway.  For example

MRSETS
/MDGROUP NAME=$health LABEL="Health status"
VARIABLES=hlth1 hlth2 hlth3 hlth4 hlth5
VALUE=1.